# What 90s TV movie has a young boy finding and raising a Godzilla-like monster to attack a bad guy?

Tags: story-identification, medieval

I'm looking for a 90s TV movie where a young boy (a prince?) finds a little monster (from a egg?). This monster grows insanely fast into a Godzilla-like thing, and with it 
he and some soldiers attack an evil guy / king or whatever. The setting was medieval.

The movie is a bit trashy and seems like TV-only.

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like Eragon, but Eragon wasn't a 90's TV movie, it just felt like it. (ZING!)

Comment: no it is way older than eragon.
and the monster was wayyyyy bigger. looks more like Godzilla.

Comment: I'm really not sure what movie this is but I hope you find out.

Comment: I know, @user1250639, I was just dissin' on the Eragon. Maybe the author ripped off the movie you're thinking of *along* with Tolkien and Star Wars.

Comment: Sounds like a medieval remake of [20 Million Miles to Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050084/)

Comment: My initial thought was Waterhorse...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it could be [The Adventures of Galgameth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Galgameth) from 1996.

It's got your prince, your monster (although it grows from a statue, not an egg), your evil king-type-guy, and the general medieval setting.

Comment: yes!!. thats it. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The movie is [Dragonworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonworld) from 1994

Comment: You might want to note that the green tick next to the other answer indicates that the OP "accepted" ZimuL8r's answer.